# Showing that a function defined by an integral is well-defined.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to show that, if $g: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has compact support and is continuous then:

$f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} \dfrac{g(x-y)}{|y|^2}dy$

is well defined. $| x |$ means the euclidean norm.

Well, my thoughts were, since $g$ has compact support, there exist $C >0$ such that $|g(x)|<C, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^4$. Therefore

$|f(x)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} \dfrac{|g(x-y)|}{|y|^2}dy \leq C \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} \dfrac{1}{|y|^2}dy$.

Now I just can't show the last integral converges. I tried to use spherical coordinates but I find that the integral actually diverges.

Comment: Tthe support of g is a compact, say K, thus the last integral is taken only on K. Can you finish?

Comment: If $C\ne 0$, the constant function $C$ does not have compact support. By replacing $f(x)$ with $C$ on _all_ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ you are giving up the compact support that you originally had.

Comment: You are right, my mistake was on the last integral, the last integral is $C \int_{K} \dfrac{1}{|y|^2} dy$ where $K$ is the compact set where $g$ is not zero$.

Comment: In my comment, I meant $g(x-y)$, not $f(x)$.

Comment: It seems that you only need to worry about the part of $\mathbb{R}^4$ near $y=0$. Now the argument using the constant "$C$" is relevant (note the exponent in the denominator is greater than $1$). For the rest of $\mathbb{R}^4$, the compact set $K$ saves you.

Comment: @Lucas: Sorry -- the key is not that the exponent is greater 1; rather, the key is that the exponent is less than 5/2. To see this, try your problem  for the case where g is constant, equal to 1 say, and where K is the unit 4-ball. Then calculate the integral with the value x = 0.